# Validate time in relation to a checkbox is checked or not?

Tags: laravel, validation, checkbox, time

I have 3 input fields (reservationdate, starttime, endtime) and 1 checkbox (holeday).
If the checkbox clicked I do not need starttime and endtime. On the other hand starttime and endtime is required.
What can I do to solve this task?

I tried in Laravel the required_if validation-function. But I'm certainly using it wrong

```php
// ReservationController store:
$data = $request->validate([
    'userid' => 'required|numeric',
    'vehicleid' => 'required|numeric',
    'budgetid' => 'required|numeric',
    'reservationdate' => 'required|date',
    'starttime' => 'required_if:holeday,on|date_format:H:i|before_or_equal:endtime',
    'endtime' => 'date_format:H:i',
    'holeday' => 'boolean'
]);
```

**index.blade.php (only the checkbox)**

```html
<div class="input-field col s2">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="holeday" class="filled-in"  />
        <span>Hole Day</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

If the checkbox is checked I get the error-message "The starttime field is required when holeday is on." but in this case I need no error. Hey user it is OK. I don´t need a starttime or endtime. Your clicked the holeday.

Comment: Shouldn't the start time and end time be required when the whole day is off? I think your logic is reversed

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am mistaken: you are trying to have `starttime` and `endtime` required only when `holeday` is not checked.

If I recall correctly when a checkbox is unchecked or disabled, it isn't sent at all to the server, so you can verify for the presence/absence of that field name:

```php
// ReservationController store:
$data = $request->validate([
    'userid' => 'required|numeric',
    'vehicleid' => 'required|numeric',
    'budgetid' => 'required|numeric',
    'reservationdate' => 'required|date',
    'starttime' => 'required_without:holeday|date_format:H:i|before_or_equal:endtime',
    'endtime' => 'required_without:holeday|date_format:H:i',
    'holeday' => 'required_without_all:starttime,endtime|in:on'
]);
```

**Note:** `boolean` validations accepts only `true`, ``` 1``and "1" ``` as thruthy values. But if the checkbox is set without a value attribute you would get `"on"` value as default check value.

However if you pass all of the three fields with their respective values, the validation would still pass, because required doesn't ensure that if the condition is not met that field must not be present.

You can take that into account and just write your logic to check if holeday has "on" value then ignore starttime and endtime values and viceversa.

Otherwise, you have to use a custom validation rule like this one **(untested)**:

```php
Validator::extend('not_present_with', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
        if (! Arr:has($validator->attributes(), $parameter)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return ! Arr::has($validator->attributes(), $attribute);
});
```

Then use the following validation rules:

```php
// ReservationController store:
$data = $request->validate([
    'userid' => 'required|numeric',
    'vehicleid' => 'required|numeric',
    'budgetid' => 'required|numeric',
    'reservationdate' => 'required|date',
    'starttime' => 'not_present_with:holeday|required_without:holeday|date_format:H:i|before_or_equal:endtime',
    'endtime' => 'not_present_with:holeday|required_without:holeday|date_format:H:i',
    'holeday' => 'not_present_with:starttime,endtime|required_without_all:starttime,endtime|in:on'
]);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer mdexp. I think "holeday" is misleading. I mean with this a whole day event (24 hours). It is not necessary for the user to write a starttime and endtime if he clicked (request value is "on") the whole day checkbox.
If I try your first code (not the Validator) and I checked the checkbox and starttime,endtime empty I get the error "... date_format:H:i.

Comment: Try to add `bail|` in front of the last three rules (before the required_without rules). This tells Laravel to stop validation of the remaining rules of a field in one fails. For example if the required_without fails, then the date_format would not be validated

Comment: Hi mdexp. I found the bail and I try it. Without success :-((. At the moment I check your second code with Validator. I hope I fix it with them. I hope you know what I want to do with this form. I don´t know if this is a good practice???